# HDFS dfs.name.dir is out of free space

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

**Spark application throws this error:**

```
> Cannot create directory
> /home/user/hdp/.sparkStaging/application_00000000_000. Name node is in
> safe mode. Resources are low on NN.  Please add or free up more
> resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:  If you turn off
> safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to
> safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
```

So I tried this: **hdfs dfs -df -h**

```
Filesystem                                                          Size   Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.xxxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.compute.internal:xxxx  58.5 G  5.0 G     46.5 G    9%
```

since it has enough free space, i tried doing **df -h**, and found out that 
**${dfs.name.dir} = /xx2/namenode** consumed all of free space (27G) in /xxx/xxxx3

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
xxxxxxxx        3.9G   72K  3.9G   1% /xxx
xxxxx           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /xxx/shm
/xxx/xxxx1      9.8G  3.8G  5.9G  40% /
/xxx/xxxx2      5.0G   65M  5.0G   2% /xx1
/xxx/xxxx3       27G   27G   94M 100% /xx2
```

I dont know how to properly free some space for that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your `safemode` threshold value in `hdfs-default.xml`

```
dfs.safemode.threshold.pct
dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct
```

Try increasing the threshold,then you use below to leave safemode. After that you can revert back the changes once you have found your black sheep file causing  the issue

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

You can check for local files(`/var/log/..`) as hadoop works on top of disk space of system.Also check for the directories mentioned in `hadoop.tmp.dir`.Use `hadoop fs -rmr` on all data nodes and name node to flush

Comment: dfs.safemode.threshold.pct and dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct is not specified in hdfs-site.xml

Comment: local files were not exceeding above 1GB. I think the edit logs in hadoop took a lot of space in ${dfs.name.dir}. Setting an upper limit of how many edits/updates logs in hdfs may have solved this issue. I am not sure tho. I decided to relaunch the emr since i wasnt able to start hdfs when I stopped it.